# How should t the className selector of input fields change the value iside?

Tags: javascript, input, focus, onfocus

If we have multiple fields of inputs each one having a difrent value of a string.

```
<input type="text" class="info" value="Enter Name">
<input type="text" class="info" value="Enter Lastname">
```

How would we be able to onfocus to the input fields inside . As an example i use the method of only ONE input field, as shown below in the code:

```
  info.onfocus=function(){
    if(info.value=="Enter Name"){
        info.value=" ";
    }
   }
```

Now as i sad that code is only for one input field that i took as an example. How is it possible to focus on bouth of the input fields as i asked above. I know that i have to loop trough the input fields since bouth of them have the same class name. For any help from your friends i want to thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set onFocus inside input field and then use event.target.value to access specified input value.

```html
<html>
<script>
  function _focus(ev) {
    ev.target.value = '';
  }
</script>
  <input type="text" onFocus="_focus(event);" class="info" value="Enter Name">
</html>
```

EDIT:

```html
<html>
<script>
  function _focus(ev) {
    ev.target.value = '';
  }
   
  function _blur(ev){
    if(ev.target.value == ''){
      if(event.target.id == 1) ev.target.value = "Enter Name"
      if(event.target.id == 2) ev.target.value = "Enter Lastname"
    }
  }
   
</script>
<input id="1" type="text" onFocus="_focus(event);" onBlur="_blur(event)" class="info" value="Enter Name">
<input id="2" type="text" onFocus="_focus(event);" onBlur="_blur(event)" class="info" value="Enter Lastname">
</html>
```

Comment: Now that actually would run for two or maybe more inputs that have the same function onfocus=_focus(event) as you are saying chrunchips123 ?

Comment: Yes, it would work on every input with _focus. Then in function you can accesss currently focused input value, simply by using passing event, later you can use it as event.target.value

Comment: Sorry just one question , i can see you are very familir with this method , So if i would now use the onblur event for this code to return the same values for each field , how would i achive that . Im sorry maybe i am asking to much , but for the first time i have encountert this type of code ,,,, and thank you so so so much  the help churnchip123 .

Comment: I would add id to these inputs, because you have to store somewhere default values or somehow recognize current input's default value. I edited answer I made with possible example.

Comment: It works very good i checked that out , i think i have to see more about this target event , im not familiar with this . But after all chrunchips123 i want to thank you so much for the help and kindness of you , i learned something new from you.